# Generate url from regex into other in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate an url which uses regular expression like (`currentUrlRegex`:

```
currentUrlRegex = @"https://www.website.com/[a-z]{2})-[a-z]{2})/file/(.*)";
```

and will be redirected to:

```
toUrlRegex = @"https://www.website.com/$1-$2/file/system/$3";
```

If someone access like: https://www.website.com/en-en/file/123.png then redirects to https://www.website.com/en-en/file/system/123.png

I want to match current url from request (in ASP.NET MVC) with `currentUrlRegex`. If match then redirect to an url matched in `toUrlRegex` with transformation.

I have those regex urls in a file which is managed from CMS (can be added, deleted, renamed, etc)

I created an HTTP module:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    _context = context;
    context.PostResolveRequestCache += ContextOnPostResolveRequestCache;
}

private void ContextOnPostResolveRequestCache(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  string currentUrl = _context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).TrimEnd('/');

  // read all kind of regex urls from a file into a list of RedirectModel

        string redirectUrl = string.Empty;

        foreach (RedirectModel redirectModel in list) {
           try {
              string url = new Uri(redirectModel.FromUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path).TrimEnd('/');
              if (url.Equals(currentUrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                 redirectUrl = redirectModel.ToUrl;
                 break;
              }
           } catch {
              // use regex here when Uri is invalid (contains *,),(, etc)
           }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirectUrl)) {
           _context.Response.RedirectPermanent(redirectUrl);
        }
}
```

and `RedirectModel` has two simple properties of `string` type: `FromUrl` and `ToUrl`.

Can you help me how to achieve regex side ? For simple url I managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) and the strings mostly as you provided them, just with corrected parenthesis in the search pattern.

```
var input = @"https://www.website.com/en-en/file/123.png";
var output = Regex.Replace(
    input,
    @"https://www.website.com/([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/file/(.*)",
    @"https://www.website.com/$1-$2/file/system/$3");
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL conversion may look something like this

```
var input = @"https://www.website.com/en-en/file/123.png";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"https://www.website.com/([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})\/file\/(.*)");
MatchCollection m = rgx.Matches(input);

if (m.Count > 0 && m.Count == 1)
{
    var matchGroup = m[0].Groups;
    var redirecturl = string.Format("https://www.website.com/{0}-{1}/file/system/{2}", matchGroup[1].Value, matchGroup[2].Value, matchGroup[3].Value);
}
```